# JQuery replaceWith() in a Dropdown Problem

Tags: jquery, dropdown, replacewith

i'm new to JQuery an have a Problem whith the replaceWith function.

I created a Dropdown. After Click on a Dropdown Element the Icon in the first Button changes, thats what i wanted to have. But the Icon from the Dropdown List is deleted after click.

Here is my HTML

```
<button title="Kein Status" data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn btn-xs btn-link btn-outline">
    <i id="icon" class="fas fa-thermometer-empty text-danger fa-lg"></i>
</button>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><button class="dropdown-item" onclick="saveToDB(this,\'status1\',\'' . $fieldRow['id'] . '\',\'50\')"><i id="newIcon" class="fas fa-thermometer-quarter fa-lg text-warning"> </i> 50 % Status</button></li>
</ul>
```

function saveToDB

```
function saveToDB(column,id,value) {
  $.ajax({
    url: "edit.php",
    type: "POST",
    data:'column='+column+'&editval='+value+'&id='+id,
    success: function(data){
         var clone = $('#newIcon').show();
     $('#newIcon').replaceWith(clone);      
    }
  });
}
```

After Klick on the Button in Dropdownlist the Code

```
<li>
<button class="dropdown-item" onclick="saveToDB(this,\'status1\',\'' . $fieldRow['id'] . '\',\'50\')">
<i id="newIcon" class="fas fa-thermometer-quarter fa-lg text-warning"> </i> 50 % Status
</button>
</li>
```

Change to

```
<li>
<button class="dropdown-item" onclick="saveToDB(this,\'status1\',\'' . $fieldRow['id'] . '\',\'50\')"> 50 % Status
</button>
</li>
```

As far as i understand the replaceWith Function is something like a Move Function. How can i keep the Icon in the Dropdownlist?

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow! Where are you using replaceWith() ? I cannot find it in the supplied code.

Comment: Sorry i changed replaceWith to html() for testing and copied the Code without reading it again. I have edit the JQuery Part

Answer (score 0):

You need to add and remove class to your element
i.e

In success function of ajax add check

```
If($('#newIcon').hasClass('fa-thermometer-quarter'))
{
    $('#newIcon').removeClass('fa-thermometer-quarter');
    $('#newIcon').addClass('fa-check');
} else {
    $('#newIcon').removeClass('fa-check');
    $('#newIcon').addClass('fa-thermometer-quarter' );
}
```

Comment: That change the Thermometer in my first Button to fa-check, but the Icon in my dropdownlist is also deleted. The Problem is that the complete <i></i> Tag in the Dropdownlist is away.